# Python: count number of uninterrupded intervals

Tags: python, count, intervals

Consider an array Y of 0s and 1s. For example: Y = (0,1,1,0). I want to count the number of uninterrupted intervals of the 0s and 1s. In our example n0 = 2 and n1 = 1. I have a script which does the needed. It is not very elegant though. Does someone know a smoother or more pythonic version?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# storage
counter = {}

# number of random draws
n = 10

# dataframe of random draw between 0 and 1
Y = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(2, n))

# where are the 0s and 1s
idx_0 = Y[Y[0] == 0].index
idx_1 = Y[Y[0] == 1].index

# count intervals of uninterrupted 0s
j = 0
for i in idx_0:
    if i+1 < n:
        if Y.loc[i+1, 0] == 1:
            j += 1
        else:
            continue

if Y.loc[n-1, 0] == 0:
    j += 1


counter['n_0'] = j

# count intervals of uninterrupted 1s
j = 0
for i in idx_1:
    if i+1 < n:
        if Y.loc[i+1, 0] == 0:
            j += 1
        else:
            continue

if Y.loc[n-1, 0] == 1:
    j += 1

counter['n_1'] = j
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more succinct solution taking advantage of pandas methods:

```
counter = Y[0][Y[0].diff() != 0].value_counts()
```

- `Y[0].diff()` counts the difference between consecutive elements
- `diff != 0` marks the indices where the value changes
- `Y[idx].value_counts()` counts the frequency of each value

Example result for 10 random elements, [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]:

```
1    2
0    2
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

If you insist having the keys as 'n_0' and 'n_1' instead, you can rename them with

```
counter = counter.rename(index={i: f'n_{i}' for i in range(2)})
```

You can also convert that to a dict with `dict(counter)`, even though the pandas object has the same functionality with `counter[key]` giving you the respective value.

Comment: If the result of Y=(0,1,1,0) is n0 = 2 and n1=2, then this is wrong, because there are two uninterrupted intervals of 0s (n0=2) and one uninterrupted interval of 1s (n0=1).

Comment: Ok, sorry. I was thinking you were referring to the example from my original post. Maybe post the example input Y for verification. Would you also know a one-liner for numpy arrays?

Comment: @clueless For a numpy 1D array the syntax is very similar. `Counter(a[np.hstack([True, np.diff(a) != 0])])`. Where `Counter` is from the `collections` standard library and `a` is the array. You just need the add another True at the beginning to take into account the first value, because `np.diff` will give you x-1 values for x elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
numbers = [0, 1, 1, 0]
def runs(x, numbers):
  number_string = ''.join([str(n) for n in numbers])
  return len([r for r in number_string.split('1' if x == 0 else '0') if r])

print(runs(0, numbers))
print(runs(1, numbers))
```

Update using dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# storage
counter = {}

# number of random draws
n = 10

# dataframe of random draw between 0 and 1
Y = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(2, n))
print([v[0] for v in Y.values.tolist()])

def runs(x, numbers):
  number_string = ''.join([str(n) for n in numbers])
  return len([len(r) for r in number_string.split('1' if x == 0 else '0') if r])

values = [v[0] for v in Y.values.tolist()]
print(values)
print('Runs of 0: {}'.format(runs(0, values)))
print('Runs of 1: {}'.format(runs(1, values))
```

Comment: I believe the original poster was looking for the number of intervals, change that `max()` to a `len()` and don't consider zeroes.

Comment: You're right. I misunderstood. Thank you. I've updated the answer.